# Bad shading by "active" boolean (GeoNodes)

Tags: modeling, animation, shaders, geometry-nodes, animation-nodes

My "Boolean" operator uses the "Integer" value in GoeNodes, it's all in animation and I can't just *fix* it. My problem is that when applying "ShadeSmooth" my Shading is very bad.
I tried adding more geometry , but it didn 't lead to anything.

[image]

[image: MyNodes1]

[image: MyNodes2]

[FileLink](https://disk.yandex.ru/d/763HTCf8d7jepA)

Answer (score 0):

Try **Split Edges** node with *Selection* socket feed by *Mesh Boolean* node > *Intersecting Edges* socket ...

[image]

It doen't seems to be right way, but it worked in this case.

---

I just can't find how to invert selection correctly ... I expected *Math Boolean* node > *Not* type should do the job, but it didn't. Hmm ... so someone probably gives you a better idea ...

[image]